# Spring STS Eclipse -noverify

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, plugins

Running eclipse v4.7.0
Just installed STS v3.9.0.20170706

Tried to run my spring boot app through the Spring Boot console.
I have -Xmx2g -Xms1g specified as VM arguments

Running display the following error

> Invalid initial heap size: -Xms1g-noverify
>   Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

How do I stop it from appending -noverify.
Previous to this STS plugin update never had this before

Comment: More Information...  This is being caused by the new 'Fast startup' feature.  Looking at the Preferences...Spring...Boot it has "-noverify -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1" and adding a space in front of this still does not resolve the issue.  Turning off 'Fast startup' allows the app to run, but sort of defeats the purpose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a bug that has already been fixed in the current development branch (see commit *[Fix fast startup vm args addition […]](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/commit/9721bd9d9b9268a30fe8fd43116562e31aaf7a40#diff-8f3cef6868489f41dabe432e01e0b578R192)*).

So I guess it will work again with the next update…

As a workaround in the meantime you can add something like `-noverify -Ddummy=` at the end of your *VM Arguments*, so the final command line becomes `… -noverify -Ddummy=-noverify …`. Or you can disable *Fast startup*…